# How to get Sharepoint credentials to be used in an ASP Net Core app?

Tags: asp.net-core, web, iis, sharepoint

I have an ASP NET Core app that will be acessible through a Sharepoint page, once it's published to an IIS Server. 
I need to get the credentials used to access that page (Windows Authenticaton), because they will then be used to access a third link.
I'm using the Razor Pages approach, so I have no controller.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you add more details about "accessible through a Sharepoint page". Are we talking IFrames, just linking to the app, or other mechanisms?

Comment: The page has an option to open a simulator. Once the button is clicked, the simulator site opens, which should keep the credentials used to access the Sharepoint page, because, after filling some forms, the user has an option that redirects to another link, but it uses the same credentials to access it.